# nginx proxy_pass too many open files

Tags: nginx

I'm getting what seems to be just a common OS level "Too many open files" error that there are solutions already on stackoverflow.

What I want to confirm is that I am not forcing a weird proxy_pass loop.

When I go to `myapp.com` everything loads as expected.
When I go to `customdomain.com`, I get a 500 and the logs show `Too many open files`.

I'm worried that the proxy_pass at the bottom which sets the `Host` header, will cause the request to ALWAYS go back to the same server block.

More curiously, when I have a single box (i.e. the proxy_pass sends the request to the same box), I get the 500 error. But if I move the proxy_pass backend to say google.com, it proxies fine.

What can I do to determine if this is an OS level issue with my VM or if I'm forcing a redirect?

Here is the configuration:

```
server {
    listen   80 default;
    server_name  myapp.com;

    root   /usr/share/myapp/;
    index  index.php index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /control.php?$uri/;
   }
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  customdomain.com;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=10s;
        set $backend "http://myapp.com";

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass $backend;
    }
}
```